# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser with a value split

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am using `PHP` Simple `HTML DOM Parser` to scrape some values from a web site. 
I already splitted a variable called `$results` (the format is: `number:number`)
using `.str_replace` but I need to use these two numbers from `$results` individually.
This is my code:

```
require_once '../simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/belgium/jupiler-league/results/');

$match_dates = $html->find("td[class=last-cell nobr date]"); // we have 1 per match
$titles = $html->find("td[class=first-cell tl]"); // 1 per match
$results = $html->find("td[class=result]"); // 1
$best_bets = $html->find("td[class=odds best-betrate]"); // 1
$odds = $html->find("td[class=odds]"); // 2

$c = $b = 0; // two counters

foreach ($titles as $match) {
    echo $match_dates[$c]->innertext." - ".$match->innertext." ".str_replace(':',' ',$results[$c]->innertext)." - ".$best_bets[$c++]->attr['data-odd']." / ".$odds[$b++]->attr['data-odd']." / ".$odds[$b++]->attr['data-odd']."<br/>";
}
```

So I need to use these two numbers from `$results` individually and I'd like to insert all values into a `table`. 
Thanks

Comment: `list($num1, $num2) = explode(':', $results[$c]->innertext);`

Comment: I tried to implement it but I got "Array" instead of numbers...how Can I implement it in my code, please?

Comment: post the `var_dump($results[$c]->innertext)` and your current code.

Comment: @Jakumi Sorry but where should I put it?

Comment: I think I shot too soon. After looking at the link provided in the code ... what is attr['data-odd']? I think this doesn't exist.

Comment: it's "attributes" because odds values are inside tags and not between. Script is working fine but I don't know how to explode the results. Any suggestion about it? Thanks

Comment: @splash58 already provided that information. `explode(':', $results[$c]->innertext);` returns an array containing the two values. `list($var1, $var2)` will assign the values of an array to the two vars. If you don't know how to proceed, update your question with the current code. And if you would be so kind to nicely format your code, that would be splendid.

Comment: yes, but I don't understand where I have to put it. I think it's a solution but I don't know how I can implement in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @splash58 already mentions in a comment, you have to use `explode` to separate the two values easily.

```
foreach ($titles as $match) {
    list($num1, $num2) = explode(':', $results[$c]->innertext); // <- explode
    echo $match_dates[$c]->innertext .
         " - ".$match->innertext." ".$num1.':'.$num2 .          // <- example use
         " - ".$best_bets[$c++]->attr['data-odd'] .
         " / ".$odds[$b++]->attr['data-odd'] .
         " / ".$odds[$b++]->attr['data-odd'] .
         "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got an error: "Warning: explode() expects at least 2 parameters,"

Comment: oops, sorry, I forgot the ":" in the explode line